# supervisor tool logs in different format. I need JSON format

Tags: docker, supervisord

I use the tool **supervisor** https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor to build some app in a docker container.
Processes controlled with the supervisor output logs in JSON format. But supervisor outputs logs in text format.

Is there a way to make supervisor to output logs also in JSON format?

There is example:

```
2024-02-05 08:34:22,987 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
2024-02-05 08:34:22,992 INFO supervisord started with pid 19
2024-02-05 08:34:24,014 INFO spawned: 'cloudftp' with pid 20
2024-02-05 08:34:24,021 INFO spawned: 'cloudftps' with pid 21
{"context":{"process":20,"user":""},"channel":"default","datetime":"2024-02-05T08:34:24.000+0000","level_name":"CRITICAL","message":"Warning. \"tmpfolder\" in config file is /scratch/cloudftp But, such folder not exists! So, will be used /var/www/smestorage/ftpserver/tmp/"}
Undefined address for Socket::pack_sockaddr_in at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/Socket.pm line 172.
2024-02-05 08:34:24,628 INFO exited: cloudftp (exit status 255; not expected)
{"message":"Warning. \"tmpfolder\" in config file is /scratch/cloudftp But, such folder not exists! So, will be used /var/www/smestorage/ftpserver/tmp/","context":{"process":21,"user":""},"channel":"default","datetime":"2024-02-05T08:34:24.000+0000","level_name":"CRITICAL"}
2024-02-05 08:34:24,665 INFO gave up: cloudftp entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
{"datetime":"2024-02-05T08:34:24.000+0000","channel":"ftpis","level_name":"CRITICAL","context":{"process":21,"user":""},"message":"FTPS server (implicit FTP over TLS) disabled by option disable_ftps!"}
2024-02-05 08:34:24,671 INFO exited: cloudftps (exit status 12; not expected)
2024-02-05 08:34:25,673 INFO gave up: cloudftps entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

I need all logs of my docker container to be JSON. What can i do with supervisor logging config to achieve this?

Comment: A good article about JSON logging: https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/json-logging/